# ocanvas, svg is not rendered

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-10

Hello i use ocanvas framewrok for canvas created page, i encountered problem with rendering swg images into it.

Internet explorer 10 :

this works :

```
var imagee = canvas.display.image({
    x: 177,
    y: 120,
    origin: { x: "center", y: "center" },
    image: "/web/upload/svg/2014-06-09/1.png"
});
```

this does not work , no image is drawn:

```
var imagee = canvas.display.image({
    x: 177,
    y: 120,
    origin: { x: "center", y: "center" },
    image: "/web/upload/svg/2014-06-09/1.svg"
});
```

this works :

```
<img src = "/web/upload/svg/2014-06-09/1.svg"> </img>
```

in head i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and meta

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Ocanvas with svg image is working in chrome firefox, but not with ie10, in ie10 there is no error in js console. What do i do in bad way ?

Comment: As from 2.7.2 its fixed. https://github.com/koggdal/ocanvas/issues/97#issuecomment-46375528

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from 2.7.2 its fixed. github.com/koggdal/ocanvas/issues/97#issuecomment-46375528